# C# создать ежемесячную таблицу для учителей

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть счетчик учителей (int х = 11) и дней в выбранный месяц (int month = 29).

Я хочу случайно добавить учителей дней в месяц минимум повторявший учителя.

Например, у меня есть: 29 дней и 11 преподавателей

для этого, пример 4 учителя должны учить два дня урока в месяц
и 7 учителя должны преподавать три дня в месяц

и результат должен быть:

4 Учитель * 2 урока = 8

7 Учитель * 3 урока = 21

Итого: 29

Хочу чтобы автоматический рассчитал и справедливо поставил дни в таблицу.
Как минимум мне нужна идея или алгоритм для решения этой проблемы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

### Алгоритм

Пусть задан массив имён учителей `$names` и количество дней `$days`в текущем месяце.

Решение можно построить на функции `random_slice($arr, $num)` возвращающей случайную выборку длины num без повторений из массива `arr` - как будто мы написали элементы массива на бумажках и поочерёдно их тянем `num` раз.

Программно это реализовано так:

1. Вычисляем `$cnt` как размерность массива `$arr`.
2. Повторяем `$num` раз:
   2.1. Случайно выбрать индекс `$i` в диапазоне `0...$cnt-1`.
   2.2. `$arr[$i]` записать в массив `$result` очередным номером.
   2.3. Уменьшить `$cnt` на 1.
   2.4. `$arr[$cnt]` записать на место `$arr[$i]`.
3. `result` - требуемая выборка.

Теперь достаточно:

1. Рандомно выбрать учителей на лишние 7 дней `$list = random_slice($names, 7)` .
2. Дополнить его массивом `names` до требуемой длины `29`.
3. Рандомно создать график `$shedule = random_slice($list, 29)`

### Текст программы на PHP:

```
$names = ["Name01", "Name02", "Name03", "Name04","Name05", "Name06", "Name07", "Name08", "Name09", "Name10", "Name11"];
$days = 29;

print "days = $days<br>names:"; 
var_dump($names);

function random_slice($arr, $num){
    $result = [];
    $cnt = count($arr);
    for($n = 0; $n < $num; $n++){
        $index = mt_rand(0, --$cnt);
        $result[] = $arr[$index];
        $arr{$index} = $arr[$cnt];
    }
    return $result;
}

$num = $days % count($names);
$list = random_slice($names, $num);
print "num = $num<br>list:";
var_dump($list);
while(count($list) < $days){
    $list = array_merge($list, $names);
}
print "merged list:";
var_dump($list);

$shedule = random_slice($list, $days);
print "shedule:";
var_dump($shedule);
```

### Результаты:

```
days = 29
names:
array (size=11)
  0 => string 'Name01' (length=6)
  1 => string 'Name02' (length=6)
  2 => string 'Name03' (length=6)
  3 => string 'Name04' (length=6)
  4 => string 'Name05' (length=6)
  5 => string 'Name06' (length=6)
  6 => string 'Name07' (length=6)
  7 => string 'Name08' (length=6)
  8 => string 'Name09' (length=6)
  9 => string 'Name10' (length=6)
  10 => string 'Name11' (length=6)
num = 7
list:
array (size=7)
  0 => string 'Name03' (length=6)
  1 => string 'Name08' (length=6)
  2 => string 'Name07' (length=6)
  3 => string 'Name01' (length=6)
  4 => string 'Name06' (length=6)
  5 => string 'Name02' (length=6)
  6 => string 'Name10' (length=6)
merged list:
array (size=29)
  0 => string 'Name03' (length=6)
  1 => string 'Name08' (length=6)
  2 => string 'Name07' (length=6)
  3 => string 'Name01' (length=6)
  4 => string 'Name06' (length=6)
  5 => string 'Name02' (length=6)
  6 => string 'Name10' (length=6)
  7 => string 'Name01' (length=6)
  8 => string 'Name02' (length=6)
  9 => string 'Name03' (length=6)
  10 => string 'Name04' (length=6)
  11 => string 'Name05' (length=6)
  12 => string 'Name06' (length=6)
  13 => string 'Name07' (length=6)
  14 => string 'Name08' (length=6)
  15 => string 'Name09' (length=6)
  16 => string 'Name10' (length=6)
  17 => string 'Name11' (length=6)
  18 => string 'Name01' (length=6)
  19 => string 'Name02' (length=6)
  20 => string 'Name03' (length=6)
  21 => string 'Name04' (length=6)
  22 => string 'Name05' (length=6)
  23 => string 'Name06' (length=6)
  24 => string 'Name07' (length=6)
  25 => string 'Name08' (length=6)
  26 => string 'Name09' (length=6)
  27 => string 'Name10' (length=6)
  28 => string 'Name11' (length=6)
shedule:
array (size=29)
  0 => string 'Name07' (length=6)
  1 => string 'Name08' (length=6)
  2 => string 'Name01' (length=6)
  3 => string 'Name02' (length=6)
  4 => string 'Name07' (length=6)
  5 => string 'Name04' (length=6)
  6 => string 'Name10' (length=6)
  7 => string 'Name11' (length=6)
  8 => string 'Name10' (length=6)
  9 => string 'Name07' (length=6)
  10 => string 'Name09' (length=6)
  11 => string 'Name04' (length=6)
  12 => string 'Name05' (length=6)
  13 => string 'Name03' (length=6)
  14 => string 'Name01' (length=6)
  15 => string 'Name08' (length=6)
  16 => string 'Name06' (length=6)
  17 => string 'Name05' (length=6)
  18 => string 'Name10' (length=6)
  19 => string 'Name09' (length=6)
  20 => string 'Name08' (length=6)
  21 => string 'Name01' (length=6)
  22 => string 'Name03' (length=6)
  23 => string 'Name03' (length=6)
  24 => string 'Name11' (length=6)
  25 => string 'Name06' (length=6)
  26 => string 'Name02' (length=6)
  27 => string 'Name02' (length=6)
  28 => string 'Name06' (length=6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой метод

1. Создать массив с 29 элементами
2. добавить ID учетелей столько раз, сколько урока. для 4 учителя их ID добавить в этот массив по 2 раза, а для 7 учителей по 3 раза.
3. перемешать этот массив. Нужно изменить местами элементы рандомно.
4. опуионально можно добавить проверку на последуюшую одинаковую ID. Что бы 2 ID подряд не приходили. если есть, поменять местами 2го одинакового ID с последуюшими
5. у вас массив готов. каждый индекс массива это день в календаре

---

Вариант №2

покажу в примере

1) есть данные

4 Учитель * 2 урока = 8 - пусть будут (1,2,3,4)

7 Учитель * 3 урока = 21 - пусть будут (5,6,7,8,9,10,11)

2) создаем 2 массива из A[4] и B[7] элементов. Заполняем первый с элементами (1,2,3,4) и второй с (5,6,7,8,9,10,11)

3) создаем массивы С[8] и D[21]

4) Перемешываем массив A и добавляем в массив С. Делаем 2 раза. 
Так же делаем для массивов B и D только 3 раза.

К примеру:

```
A[] = {1,2,3,4}
A[перемешка] = {4,1,3,2}
C[] = {4,1,3,2}
A[перемешка] = {2,4,3,1}
C[] = {4,1,3,2,2,4,3,1}

B[] = {5,6,7,8,9,10,11}
B[перемешка] = {5,6,7,8,9,10,11}
D[] = {5,6,7,8,9,10,11}
B[перемешка] = {9,10,5,6,7,8,11}
D[] = {5,6,7,8,9,10,11,9,10,5,6,7,8,11}
B[перемешка] = {8,9,10,11,5,6,7}
D[] = {5,6,7,8,9,10,11,9,10,5,6,7,8,11,8,9,10,11,5,6,7}
```

3) теперь нужно собрать. для этого нужен массив X[29]
теперь берем рандомно из 2 массивов и добавляем а массив X[]

Пример

```
C[] = {4,1,3,2,2,4,3,1}
D[] = {5,6,7,8,9,10,11,9,10,5,6,7,8,11,8,9,10,11,5,6,7}
X[] = {5,6,4,7,1,3,8,2,9,10,2,11,9,4,10,5,6,7,3,8,11,8,9,1,10,11,5,6,7}
```

Comment: я чуть чуть запутался . можно пример кода ?

Comment: @Kesha кода не будет. вы же алгоритм спрашивали

Comment: Выбор учителей на 2 урока и на 3 урока должен тоже быть случайным